# UIToolBar selected button state

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ios, uitoolbar

I have a UItableView with a toolbar in the bottom. The toolbar has two buttons say 'fruits','vegetables'. Clicking on them will display only the corresponding category.

I have managed to get the displaying feature working, but i do not know how to set the button in selectedState when chosen.

I created the toolbar as shown below

```
UIBarButtonItem *fruits = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Fruits" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(fruitsClicked:)];
UIBarButtonItem *vegetables = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Vegetables" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(vegetablesClicked:)];
NSArray *items = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: fruits,vegetables,nil];
[fruits release];
[vegetables release];
[self setToolBarItems:items];
```

and selectors like

```
-(void)fruitsClicked:(id)sender{
     //code here
}
```

Since i release the buttons earlier, i am not able to set

```
fruits.enabled=NO;
```

ANy help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think adding separate Buttons to do that is not a good design and strategy, you should use a UISegmentad control which is a component design for what you want: have one segment selected among X.

You can use it like this (to select the first item for example):

```
UISegmentedControl *segment = [[UISegmentedControl alloc] initWithItems:array];
[segment setSelectedSegmentIndex:0];
```

And to get the selected item:

```
segment.selectedSegmentIndex
```

Comment: how do i add the UISegementedControl to the toolbar ?

Comment: [toolBar setItems:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:segment, nil]];

Comment: Sorry.I lost you somewhere. 
Can you please show me how do i create the array. 
Is it like 
`NSArray *items=[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"fruits",@"vegetables"];`

If so how do i set the selector methods ?

Comment: @Narayanan: You can drag and drop UISegmentedControl from the XIB onto the toolbar.

Answer (score 0):

The sender argument passed to your fruitClicked handler will be a pointer to the UIBarButtonItem.  You can cast it like this:

```
[((UIBarButtonItem*)sender) setEnabled:NO];
```

However, once the button is disable it no longer accepts taps (i.e. you couldn't tap it again to re-enable it).  I would use a customView for the button and implement the enabled/disable appearance yourself.

Comment: If you really do just want to implement a set of buttons where only one at a time is selected though, you should follow Ludovic's suggestion and use a UISegmentedControl.

Comment: yes..agreed. How do i add the segmented control to the toolbar.?

Answer (score -1):

I do not have any experience with UIToolBars, but from what i see, the selector gets the ID of the sender, right? You can use that to access the clicked button, and then set it selected.

Comment: There is no way to access a standard UIButton from a UIBarButtonItem, hence no way to `select` it, either.